# Java using a resource within a ScheduledExecutorService

Tags: java, resources

Suppose there is a ScheduledExecutorService that uses a resources such as a Scanner or PrintWriter.

Would it be more efficient to have the Executor re-open the resource every time it executes, or would it be better to do something else like housing the Executor inside the try with resources block and in that way effectively having the resource remain open for the entire duration that the program is running? Would doing this weigh more heavily on the CPU than contently opening and closing the resource?

Does the answer depend on the frequency of the Executor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's always a good practice to have the resources closed after finishing the work. If opening and closing of resources is a costly operation then delegate their management to another component, usually a pool, that will control a number of opened connections to a resource. Its clients are going to continue using the same API requesting for opening of a resource and its closing upon finishing a task.

Take a look at database connection pools ([Apache DBCP](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/) or [c3p0](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/)) and their usage for an inspiration.